# Interstitial when game is over

Tags: ios, admob, sprite-kit, interstitial

I've developed an IOS Sprite Kit game with AdMob banners. I would like to add Interstitials to, but not when the game starts. I have a GameOverScene where the interstitial should show up. Not when the game starts, but every time the game is over (when GameOverScene is loaded)

This is my code:
ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import "GADBannerView.h"
#import "GADInterstitial.h"

@class GADBannerView, GADRequest;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<GADBannerViewDelegate>
{
    GADBannerView *bannerView_;
    GADInterstitial *interstitial_;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong)GADBannerView *bannerView;
-(GADRequest *)createRequest;
-(void)createInterstitial;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Other code
    Interstitial
    interstitial_ = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    interstitial_.delegate = self;
    interstitial_.adUnitID = MyInterstitialUnitID;
    [interstitial_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

    //Other code

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this  [googleads sample for interstitals](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/tree/master/admob/InterstitialExample).
You will need to add `interstitialDidReceiveAd` method to set a flag that ad is recieved  and then when your game is over call this `[interstitial_ presentFromRootViewController:self];` if you find the flag as true.
EDIT :-
Also to reload the ad again, you can add `interstitialDidDismissScreen` method to call `[interstitial_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];`

Comment: How does one do this more then once though?

Comment: @JohnRiselvato use `interstitialDidDismissScreen` method and  add `[interstitial_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];` to it. This will reload a new ad which can be reused the same way